# In that context no one would think you were being serious

Tags: dependent-clause

Suppose A, B, and C are friends. One day, A and B were having some conversation. During the conversation A said something about B jokingly. B didn't get the joke, felt offended and left the place angrily. Later on A met C and told him all that had happened. After listening to the whole story C replied: "I think the context is pretty clear. In that context no one would think you were being serious."

Now take this sentence, please:

*In that context no one **would** think you **were** being serious*.

Q: What time does "were" refer to? Does it refer to the time when the event actually took place (ie **real** past, when A said it to B), or does the sentence have a **purely** hypothetical meaning: *In such a context no one **would** think you **were** being serious*. (here "were" **does not** refer to the actual event, rather it refers to a hypothetical time as is referred by "would" in the main clause)

Comment: 'I think the context is pretty clear' speaks of the immediate context, so we're talking about a punctive (even if the narration / storming off took a few minutes) event. So 'were' refers to the time of utterance, again within those few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C might as well have replied-- *In that context no one would have thought you were being serious*.

This version is relevant insofar as the duration of the conversation and the participants thereof are concerned.

*In that context no one would think you were being serious*.

This version is more of a general statement and you are assuming that *no one in particular* (whether they were a part of the conversation or not) would think you were being serious.

Sometimes however, *will* and *would* are used almost interchangeably, although there is a slight difference in meanings still.

For example, this:

*In *such* a context no one would/will think you *are* being serious* (assuming you're hypothesizing a particular situation).

This however doesn't refer to a past situation.

Comment: You say: "In such a context no one **will** think you are being serious" --- Do we use "will" to hypothesize a situation?

Comment: I don't think that's what I meant.

Comment: Could you please explain what you meant when you said, "*assuming you're hypothesizing a particular situation*"?

Comment: I guess I was talking about an imagined future event and hypothesizing a similar situation, like the one in your question. Then someone might say to you-- *In such a situation (if it occurs), no one will think you are being serious*.

Comment: One last question: When I say: *In that context no one **would** think you **were** being serious.*---Are we talking about an imagined future event with "would think"? Also is the word "were" referring to the imagined future event rather than the actual event in the past?